# Hide/delete stats from specific domain in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Another website is using (by mistake, I guess), our GA code, so we're getting all stats of this website in our Analytics.

I noticed that two days after this website started to send its data. I set up a filter to only include data from our host name, and we're contacting the owners to warn them.

But now, is there a way for me to hide (or delete?) these entries from my Analytics?  I cannot succeed finding a way to achieve this with data already recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Data that has been collected and processed by Google cannot be modified or altered or deleted; it is part of your permanent data now. You can create a segment that can be used to exclude those specific sessions though. Perhaps you can exclude them by hostname since you suspect the hits are coming from your code being placed on a different site (eg. www.notmysite.com).

If the other party does not immediately change their tracking code, then an alternate solution would be to start a new view that filters out hits to their hostname (www.notmysite.com).

Comment: I did edit my default view with a filter that only include my domain, but I cannot find a way to hide previously collected data from this website. How can I exclude these data with the wrong  domain name in a view?

Comment: As I mentioned, try to create a segment that gets applied to the view. This is the closest you can get to "hiding" data.